# Min Cut with Vertices

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms

I have an undirected graph `G` with a set of vertices and edges. Each vertex has a weight *w*. Let's assume we have all vertices connected with some paths. I'm looking for a variant of the min-cut problem. I search for a subdivision of the graph into two parts which are connected by a group of vertices which weights sum up to a minimum value. Can you give me a pointer or a name to the problem (if it exists already)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is called *weighted vertex connectivity*. See for instance "Computing Vertex Connectivity: New Bounds from Old Techniques" by Henzinger, Rao and Gabow ([link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196677499910556)).